# PEAR PDO - MySQL to return one associated array?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, pear

I am using `PEAR's PDO library` to grab out the results I need.

Whilst I know I could just manually rebuild the array when the results are in, I was wondering is there a internal function I have missed that might do this for me when grabbing results directly from the `DB`?

**Currently:**

```
function get($query){
    $affected =& $this->conn->query($query);

    // Always check that result is not an error
    if (PEAR::isError($affected)) {
        die($affected->getMessage());
    }
    $res = $affected->fetchAll();
    return $res;
}
```

**Returns**

```
[sexnumbers] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [sex] => 1
                [no] => 35
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [sex] => 2
                [no] => 17
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [sex] => 3
                [no] => 3
            )
    )
```

**Wanted Result Set**

```
[sexnumbers] => Array
    (
        [sex] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 3
            )

        [no] => Array
            (
                [0] => 35
                [1] => 17
                [2] => 3
            )
    )
```

Comment: Do you realize that NO function can rebuild your array "when grabbing results directly from the DB"? *Any* function that can do that behind the scenes will be no more than syntax sugar

Comment: I don't want it to rebuild, I want the results to be returned to me that way... Is that so difficult? In my mind they are different things, if i wanted DB to 'rebuild' the results then I wouldn't need PHP... well u know.

Comment: Then this is about query, not PDO.

Comment: Then my understand of what PDO is is completely twisted :) I admit I know little about backend services, FE myself :(

Comment: PDO is just abstract layer to interact with DB. All logical operations you should implement in your PHP-code or on Database-side (procedures?).